# integrating react project into another react project

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react. I grabbed the petclinic project from github (https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-reactjs) to run it and understand how react works. I want to add plugins to this project (plugins are other react projects as I understand), The plugin I want to add is a datatable (https://github.com/rishabhbits038/react-tabelify) which is another react project. My question is how to integrate one react project inside the other. in jquery it is direct, just including the .js file in the project but in react it does not seem that obvious.

Comment: There's some nuance to this, but typically you just `npm install` the component and import it wherever you want to use it.

Comment: I do npm install for the petclinic project then I want to import the other project into the first one, I can't npm install the second one because if I need to integrate more plugins I will nor npm install all of them to run my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside the petclinic project, run

`npm install react-tabelify`

and import the component you want use as:

`import Tabelify from 'react-tabelify';`

should work, as the second library is registered with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabelify)

Comment: missing string in import

Comment: I would suggest changing to `npm install react-tabelify --save`

Comment: I will try this solution and report in the comments. Thank you guys.

Comment: when you run `npm install react-tabelify --save`, all contents of `react-tabelify` gets downloaded into `node_modules` folder of petclinic, and you may import as said above

Comment: That sounds great! Let's suppose now that the project is not registered in npm, does this way still work?

Comment: forgive me for my naive questions, I just started react yesterday:P

Comment: No. You will have to clone the project source files, then import required components using correct path, like `import Tabelify from '../../react-tabelify'`

Comment: Thank you very much Dane:))

Comment: this is old question , but you can use this repository : http://github.com/nimahkh/react-all-in-one-package it helps me